# Explicitly disabling events for Shield UI JavaScript Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, shieldui

I am looking for an answer to the question how (and whether) it is possible to disable explicitly events (or certain events) for my Shield UI Charts based on certain factors. For instance whether user is logged or not and so on. I looked at the documentation but there isn’t such property. For instance I see the functions that handle the different events:

```
events: {
    seriesClick: function(args) {
    // handle event
    }
}
```

but there isn’t a property like
events: true
or something like that.
And my other question is, is there a way to indirectly disable one or more events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is to take into account which events will be enabled and disabled before the rendering of the chart. Than you simply put the appropriate events code shall it be allowed for the current use privileges.
There is also a way for indirect events disabling. For instance the series related events such as pointDeselect and pointSelect may be practically disabled by using the enablePointSelection property. Below is a code sample for the area chart type:

```
seriesSettings: {
    area: {
        enablePointSelection: false
    }
}
```

Once we disable the series points to be selected the appropriate code may exist but won’t be executed.